# Run .exe file using AngularJs on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, activexobject

I am using angularjs for web application we wount run exe file,
which is present on client machine like (NotePad,calculator) 
we use context Menu on which this application needs to run.
I found lot's for code like

```
<script>
function LaunchApp() {
if (!document.all) {
  alert ("Available only with Internet Explorer.");
  return;
}
var ws = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
ws.Exec("C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe");
}
</script>
```

but this code need to put in .hta file so how we can call this
function from angular Controller we use 'use strict' for each .js file

Comment: Eeeck.  What a giant security hole if that was ever allowed.  How about letting a browser do this: `ws.Exec("cmd erase *.* <y");`?

Comment: you cant run client applications using javascript..and If this exe is built by you then create  a protocol to open the exe from web like  myprotocol://myapp.exe

Comment: can please add sample code.

Comment: @optimus this isnt javascript... it is it's ugly brother JScript. A EcmaScript wrapper for MS Visual Basic It does allow such things. Or at least it used to in the golden days of IE6 supremacy

Comment: just google " how to create custom protocols  in c#" or the language you used for creating the exe

Comment: @MichaelDibbets yeah the time when IE was the only option :p